# Date Regular expression php

Tags: php, regex

I have a regular expression which is validating my below date format

4-may-14  and 13 oct 2013

But i want a regular expression which will validate my below date formats also
Saturday, 14 December, 2013 1:22:06 PM and
14Dec2013

I have implemented below code

```
 <?php

     $toMatch = '14Dec2013';

     if(preg_match_all('/\d{1,2}\W[a-z,]{3,7}\W\d{2,4}/i', $toMatch, $regs))
     {
           echo "true";
     }
     else
     {     
           echo "false";     
     }

 ?>
```

Any help will be appreciated 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please search for "date validation regex" and you will find MANY MANY answers.  You are not the first person to want to do this, so try to find existing code that has already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to accomplish? You may not need to use regex at all, depending on what your end goal is.

Answer (score 1):

[**Live demo**](http://regex101.com/r/fW0nR0)

Try this:

```
/([a-zA-Z]+, \d{1,2} [a-zA-Z]+, \d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} (PM|AM))|(\d{1,2}[ -]?[a-zA-Z]+[ -]?\d{1,4})/
```

Comment: I see worth on this Answer !!

Comment: Hello Amir 
Using above regex giving  me below warning
Warning: preg_match_all(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in D:\wamp\www\regex\go.php on line 5

Comment: @user3713677 did you add the delimiter `/` at the beginning and end of the pattern ? Check my update, I added them ...

Comment: @Amir above regex fails in many cases like Saturday, 14 December, 2013  PM
I have removed time but it  stills return true

Comment: @user3713677 check the update. I replaced `\w` by `[a-zA-Z]` to restrict the use of alpha only

Comment: @user3713677 updated again. Please check all cases now

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case it's better to just try to parse it. If it's successful, then it is valid, else it is not. This way it catches all the edge cases.

```
<?php

function validate($toMatch)
{
    $d = Datetime::createFromFormat('jMY', $toMatch);
    if ($d) return true;

    $d = Datetime::createFromFormat('l, j F, Y h:i:s A', $toMatch);
    if ($d) return true;

    return false;
}

var_dump(validate('14Dec2013'));
# bool(true)

var_dump(validate('Saturday, 14 December, 2013 1:22:06 PM'));
# bool(true)

var_dump(validate('13 oct 2013'));
# bool(false)
```

Comment: Hello user3678068
I am just searching for solution through regex only

Comment: @user3713677, I just thought doing it this way is clearer than regex. And it's nearly impossible to use regex to exclude all invalid strings, especially when 'Jan' is a valid month, but 'xyz' isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You should use alternatives and subpatterns in your regexp. They are separated by | and enclosed in (). But lets go through your current RegExp first:

```
\d{1,2} means one or two digits
\W means non-word character (hence - or space is accepted)
[a-z,]{3,7} means lowecase letters from a to z plus comma must be here 3 to 7 times
\W means non-word character again
\d{2,4} means 2 to 4 digits
```

This regexp is already bad as it is as it will accept something like "33*,,,*999" - not looking as a proper date, isn't it? :)

Now back to your original issue. Let's define regexp for 14Dec2013 first:

```
([012]\d|3[01])(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)\d{4}
```

This probably as good as it can get with regexp: it will match all good dates and exclude most of bad ones. However it will accept 30feb0001.

Now your second format of Saturday, 14 December, 2013 1:22:06 PM . I will make regexp lazy and will not check for weekday names and month names - just call them as line of word characters.

```
\w+,\s*\d{1,2}\s+\w+,\s*\d{4}\s+\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s*(am|pm)
```

which means

```
\w+ at least one or more alphabetic characters (matching week day name)
, comma
\s* space(s) or nothing
\d{1,2} one or two digits
\s+ at least one space
\w+ at least one or more alphabetic characters (matching month name)
, comma
\s* space(s) or nothing
\d{4} four digits in a row
\s+ at least one space
\d{1,2} one or two digits
: colon
\d{2} two digits
: colon
\d{2} two digits
\s* space(s) or nothing
(am|pm) either "am" or "pm" (don't forget to have "i" modifier to make regexp case insensitive)
```

Having these extra two formats you may now use ( | ) construct to put it all together with your original regexp:

^(\d{1,2}\W[a-z,]{3,7}\W\d{2,4}|([012]\d|3[01])(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)\d{4}|\w+,\s*\d{1,2}\s+\w+,\s*\d{4}\s+\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s*(am|pm))$

Stick it between // in your script and you will get what will "work" for you. Why in quotes? Because using regexps to validate such complex data is bad idea (you can get number of invalid dates to slip through) and therefore you should use Datetime class and its validation abilities. It will be even better as it will accept even formats which you did not think of.

Comment: Regex is failing in this case saturday,4-march-14hghgh PM
Do not know why 
We have used \d{4} four digits in a row
Still it is returning true

Comment: It is simple: regexp which I provided matches a substring. In your case you have valid 4-march-14 inside of your string and it matches. If you want to ensure that it matches full string you need to use ^ in the beginning to signify that matching starts from the begining and $ to match to the end of the string. I will edit final regexp in my answer to show it.